# read json, repeating group

Tags: json, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to make a windows phone application that reads a json file from a website. This json file has a repeating group and I can't seem to get the program to read all the groups.

This is an example of the json output:

```
{
    "program":{
        "title":"Carl Schmitz",
        "image_url":"http:\/\/q-music.be\/sites\/2009.q-music.be\/files\/NOA.jpg"
    },
    "noa":[
        {
            "title":"Behind Blue Eyes",
            "artist":"LIMP BIZKIT",
            "itunes_link":"http:\/\/clk.tradedoubler.com\/click?p=24379&a=1256924?url=http:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/be\/album\/behind-blue-eyes\/id14915153?i=14915155&uo=4&partnerId=2003"
        },
        {
            "title":"Alone Again",
            "artist":"ALYSSA REID",
            "itunes_link":"http:\/\/clk.tradedoubler.com\/click?p=24379&a=1256924?url=http:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/be\/album\/alone-again-original-mix\/id496520410?i=496520415&uo=4&partnerId=2003"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can someone explain me how to read this json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class structure should look something like this.  I used the awesome [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com) to generate it:

Then you should be able to deserialize directly into the RootObject. You didn't mention which serializer you were using, so the actual deserialization isn't shown here (yet).

```
public class Program
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string image_url { get; set; }
}

public class Noa
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string artist { get; set; }
    public string itunes_link { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Program program { get; set; }
    public List<Noa> noa { get; set; }
}
```